# Running a script as root at bootup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, root

I have a simple script to help me do some power saving:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 1 > /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
echo min_power > /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/link_power_management_policy
echo 1500 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs
```

I want this to run on every boot as root, tried running it by adding:

```
/bin/bash /root/power-save.sh
```

in

```
/etc/rc.local
```

and also tried by adding following to root's crontab:

```
@reboot /bin/bash /root/power-save.sh
```

no use..

Comment: Either method (`/etc/rc.local` or `@reboot`) should work. There should be something from cron in `/var/log/syslog`, and cron will send you a mail if the command produces any output such as an error message. Add `set -x` at the top of the script (just after the `#!` line) and try again. Check that the script works when you invoke it directly, of course.

Answer (score 2):

You can run the commands directly in `rc.local` instead of running a script. Just put

```
echo 1 > /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
echo min_power > /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/link_power_management_policy
echo 1500 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs
```

in `rc.local`.

Comment: tried, doesn't work.

Comment: This is weird, does it work when you issue the commands directly? How do you verify that the commands don't work?

Comment: i `cat` the files and they don't contain the text there should be. Manually running them works though.

Comment: Could you post the content of your rc.local? Also you could test if rc.local is executed at all put `echo $(date)  >> /var/test.run` in it and check `/var/test.run` after reboot. Maybe the commands are not executed because there is something missing/not loaded when rc.local is running. You could try and put a `sleep 10` at the beginning of the file...